# Erro ao tentar obter o endereço IP do cliente no ASP.NET CORE 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core

Estou pesquisando uma forma para pegar o IP do usuário logado

fiz a instalação do:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides 2.2.0
```

Na Startup adicionei no Configure :

```
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });
```

No meu controller estou pegando o IP desta forma:

```
var remoteIpAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

Estou com um erro informando que não tem suporte para a operação tentada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução mais prática
No Startup  adicionar no ConfigureServices

```
//Resolve a injeção de dependencia para a classe concreta em uma única instância Singleton 
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

No controller Adicionar :

```
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;


        public NomeController(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;

        }
```

Depois e só chamar, quando on-line vai pegar o IP correto :

```
    var ip = _accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
    if (ip == "::1")
        ip = "127.0.0.1";
```